# Is there a limit when zombie process will stop?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, zombie-process

I have one dynamic cron schedule module. Using that module user can set up a cron. Basically there is a lots of DB fields which user wants to export. So user can select fields which they wants to export and schedule the cron.

To manage all of those dynamic crons, i have one static cron in place, which will run every hour and check if there is any dynamic cron to run and if cron found it will execute those crons.

Now there are lots of crons, so i have used kind of hack to run all of crons simultaneously.

```
<?php
public function actionCrondynamic()
{
    while(ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
    header('Connection: close');
    ignore_user_abort();
    ob_start();
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();

    $AllDynCronmodel = Cron::model()->findAllByAttributes();
    foreach($AllDynCronmodel as $mk=>$SingleCronModel)
    {   
        $CronId=$SingleCronModel->id;
        if(is_numeric($CronId))
        {
            $curl_url     = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('cron/runcron') . "&id=$CronId";
            $chu = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
            curl_setopt($chu, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
            curl_exec($chu);
            curl_close($chu);
        }
    }
}


public function actionRuncron($id)
{
        /* close connection start */
        while(ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
        header('Connection: close');
        ignore_user_abort();
        ob_start();
        $size = ob_get_length();
        header("Content-Length: $size");
        ob_end_flush();
        flush();
        /* Close conncetion End  */
        set_time_limit(7200);

        //Other code
        //........................
        //........................
}
?>
```

Now there is lots of complex data in it. So most complex crons take up to 20-60+ minutes. So suppose there is 30 dynamic crons, then there will be 30 zombie process will created. Now the problem is some times up to 10+ crons was not able to complete their execution and i am not able to found the reason.

So is there a limit when zombie process will kill automatically? or Some kind of Bottleneck or something else?

Note: i am using  a innodb mysql engine.

Comment: First, the crons which didn't complete  are they running fine if run alone (isolated)?

Comment: @Jakumi, yes, they are running fine, if i run them manually.

Comment: Is there any correlation between the duration of the job and it not being completed?

Comment: @Jakumi, yes if child process will kill somehow. or might be there some kind of bottle neck. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Also, at that time CPU is jumped to 20% to 75%.